# Long list in python, remove all none email (or "|") values ... and then, perhaps custom emails

Tags: python, regex, list

I've been working on something for a week. A PDF was converted automatically to XML (ERAS medical program details), a very large and imperfect result. The problem is that this strange result returned errors for a lot of things I tried. And it seems that regex doesn't work for lists, at least this one ... . I just need to have only the emails. I could do that by getting anything with "@" in it, or removing anything with "|" in it.

How can I do this? It doesn't seem like turning it into a string works. But I could be wrong.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\Iainc\Downloads\ERAS application 2022 emails.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
import re
email = ['']
for x in root.iter():
    email.append(x.text)

editedemail = ['']
search_term = 'Email:'
for i in range(len(email)-1):
    if email[i] == search_term:
        editedemail.append(email[i+1])
for i in range(len(email)-1):
    if email[i] == search_term:
        editedemail.append(email[i-1])
phonelesseditedemail = list(filter(lambda a: a != 'Phone:', editedemail))
```

The only things left to remove are entries like:

```
'Emergency Medicine | NRMP Program Code:********* | Categorical',
```

But the rest are email addresses I can use. I next afterwards want to write a program to automate sending custom emails, but for now I need to remove what I have mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including minimal code, example input, expected output, and actual output--or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). It looks like the XML aspect of the question is irrelevant, so just give us the list `email`. Also, `re` is unused.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
pipelesseditedemail = [x for x in editedemail if '|' not in x]
```

You could do all if this in one loop:

```
for i in range(len(email)):
    item1 = item2 = ''
    if i > 0:
        item1 = email[i-1]
    if i < len(email)-1:
        item2 = email[i+1]
    for item in [item1, item2]:
        if '@' in item and '|' not in item:
            editedemails.append(item)
```

Comment: I opened up a new cmd, and after creating "email", I ran your code. I got this error back: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: So, if I include what I had already done, and use your first line of code, the "list comprehension", it works. However, doing the second block returns the error I described. Thank you for the help! But may I ask what is wrong with the second block?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. `len(email-1)` should be `len(email)-1` obviously